# Test could not load file or assembly (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have struggled for quite a while trying to figure this one out. I have a Visual Studio solution (.sln file) with the following structure:

- ManagedInterfaces (c# project)
- NativeInterfaces (c++\cli project)
- NativeUnitTests (c++\cli project)

NativeInterfaces uses ManagedInterfaces. NativeUnitTests contains a unit test for a functionality in NativeInterfaces.

NativeUnitTests compiles and links with no problem, and the test appears in the test explorer. However when I run it I get "Could not load file or assembly ManagedInterfaces.dll ...." I have added a reference to it, and ManagedInterfaces.dll is in the same directory as NativeUnitTest.dll. The complete error is:

```
Test Name:  ParameterVerificarionResultCreateAndQuery
Test FullName:  Platform.NativeUnitTests.ParameterVerificationUT.ParameterVerificarionResultCreateAndQuery
Test Source:    c:\dev\smallplatform - main\prototype\platform.nativeunittests\parameterverificationut.cpp : line 18
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00,1567838

Result Message: 
Test method Platform.NativeUnitTests.ParameterVerificationUT.ParameterVerificarionResultCreateAndQuery threw exception: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadExceptionHandlerException: A nested exception occurred after the primary exception that caused the C++ module to fail to load.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception. ---> <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed to load during vtable initialization.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.EXE.

Result StackTrace:  
at ?A0x38971adc.??__E??_7SelectionResultWrapper@Selector@NativeInterfaces@Platform@@6B@@@YMXXZ()
   at _initterm_m((fnptr)* pfbegin, (fnptr)* pfend) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\puremsilcode.cpp:line 219
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializeVtables(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 332
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 493
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 703
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException(String errorMessage, Exception innerException) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\minternal.h:line 194
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 713
   at .cctor() in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 754
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.DoCallBackInDefaultDomain(IntPtr function, Void* cookie) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\minternal.h:line 410
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.DefaultDomain.Initialize() in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 278
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializeDefaultAppDomain(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 343
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 546
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 703
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowNestedModuleLoadException(Exception innerException, Exception nestedException) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\minternal.h:line 184
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Cleanup(LanguageSupport* , Exception innerException) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 663
   at <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* ) in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 712
   at .cctor() in f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\mstartup.cpp:line 754
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Platform.NativeInterfaces.Parameters.ParameterVerificationResult.{ctor}(ParameterVerificationResult* )
   at Platform.NativeUnitTests.ParameterVerificationUT.ParameterVerificarionResultCreateAndQuery() in c:\dev\smallplatform - main\prototype\platform.nativeunittests\parameterverificationut.cpp:line 18
```

The following are the logs from Assembly Binding Log Viewer:

NativeUnitTests:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.NativeUnitTests, Version=1.0.6100.27008, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeUnitTests/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeUnitTests/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file: ...

LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.NativeUnitTests, Version=1.0.6100.27008, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeUnitTests/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeUnitTests/Platform.NativeUnitTests.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file: ...

LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

NativeInterfaces:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.NativeInterfaces, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/dev/SmallPlatform - Main/Prototype/Build/x64/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/dev/SmallPlatform - Main/Prototype/Build/x64/Debug/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\dev\SmallPlatform - Main\Prototype\Build\x64\Debug\Platform.NativeInterfaces.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Platform.NativeInterfaces, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\dev\SmallPlatform - Main\Prototype\Build\x64\Debug\Platform.NativeInterfaces.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.NativeInterfaces, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeInterfaces/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeInterfaces/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file ...

LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.NativeInterfaces, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.NativeInterfaces/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.NativeInterfaces/Platform.NativeInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file ...
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Managedinterfaces:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/dev/SmallPlatform - Main/Prototype/Build/x64/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : Platform.NativeInterfaces, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/dev/SmallPlatform - Main/Prototype/Build/x64/Debug/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\dev\SmallPlatform - Main\Prototype\Build\x64\Debug\Platform.ManagedInterfaces.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\dev\SmallPlatform - Main\Prototype\Build\x64\Debug\Platform.ManagedInterfaces.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/dev/SmallPlatform - Main/Prototype/Build/x64/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : Platform.NativeInterfaces, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/dev/SmallPlatform - Main/Prototype/Build/x64/Debug/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\dev\SmallPlatform - Main\Prototype\Build\x64\Debug\Platform.ManagedInterfaces.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\dev\SmallPlatform - Main\Prototype\Build\x64\Debug\Platform.ManagedInterfaces.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file ...

LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2016 @ 16:57:46) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Platform.ManagedInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.2767, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = vstest.executionengine.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/PROGRAM FILES (X86)/MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0/COMMON7/IDE/COMMONEXTENSIONS/MICROSOFT/TESTWINDOW/Extensions/Platform.ManagedInterfaces/Platform.ManagedInterfaces.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Honestly, I'm failing to make sense of this information. Any help is much appreciated.